# How do I search through a matrix for a value and return the first column of that row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been looking high and low and can't find out a solution. It seems like i get close and then hit a wall.

I have a "Sheet 1" like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROWHEADER1 | 2432 | 1247 | 6657 | 6598 | 1234 |
| ROWHEADER2 | 6786 | 9687 | 8857 | 5425 |  |
| ROWHEADER3 | 8979 | 2157 |  |  |  |
| ROWHEADER4 | 9784 | 2215 | 3214 |  |  |

There is a "Sheet2" with this:

| A |
| --- |
| 2432 |
| 8979 |
| 6657 |
| 1234 |
| 3214 |

What I am trying to do is a lookup from column A (Sheet2) that will search Columns B:F in Sheet1 and return column A in sheet1 in column B of sheet 2.

I tried search reverse vlookup index match.. can't quite figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated

I've tried vlookups, but it is not quite what I expected. I got lost when trying to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$F$4)/($B$1:$F$4=I1),1))
```

[image]

For Office 365 we can use FILTER:

```
=@FILTER($A$1:$A$4,BYROW($B$1:$F$4,LAMBDA(a,ISNUMBER(MATCH(I1,a,0)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I'd advise to use AGGREGATE option `6` (ignore errors) instead of `7` (ignore errors and hidden items) . But that's a matter of choice I guess.

Comment: If there are no hidden lines then 6 and 7 are the same.  IF there are hidden, my guess is that the OP would not want them included.  @P.b  I almost always use 7 when answering as it is more likely than just 6 to be wanted.

Comment: I honestly didn't know what 7 did and had to search it prior to my previous comment, but yes. I guess you're right. I'm thinking more in the direction that somebody may not be the only user in a file and somebody else may hide rows and they will not show as a result. It's both good and I guess this post may benefit to sstecht's understanding of AGGREGATE.

Comment: Thank you. This worked very well for me. I used the first formula!

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup In Multiple Columns

In Microsoft 365, you could use this spilling formula:

```
=LET(sv,Sheet1!A1:A4,sl,Sheet1!B1:F4,dl,A1:A5,
    sc,COLUMNS(sl),sr,INT((XMATCH(dl,TOCOL(sl))-1)/sc+1),
        INDEX(sv,sr))
```

[image]
[image]

**Formulas**

```
D1    =TOCOL(Sheet1!B1:F4)  
E1    =XMATCH(A1:A5,D1#)    
F1    =INT((E1#-1)/COLUMNS(Sheet1!B1:F4)+1) 
G1    =INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A4,F1#)
```

**Substitution**

```
F1#   =INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A4,INT((E1#-1)/COLUMNS(Sheet1!B1:F4)+1)) 
E1#   =INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A4,INT((XMATCH(A1:A5,D1#)-1)/COLUMNS(Sheet1!B1:F4)+1))   
H1 (D1#) 
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A4,INT((XMATCH(A1:A5,TOCOL(Sheet1!B1:F4))-1)/COLUMNS(Sheet1!B1:F4)+1))
```

**LET**

```
B1    =LET(sv,Sheet1!A1:A4,sl,Sheet1!B1:F4,dl,A1:A5,
              sc,COLUMNS(sl),sr,INT((XMATCH(dl,TOCOL(sl))-1)/sc+1),
                  INDEX(sv,sr)) 

sv    Source Value Range
sl    Source Lookup Range
dl    Destination Lookup Range
sc    Source Columns Count
sr    Source Row
```